# Custom highlighted text with repeated background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got myself into a situation and cannot figure out how to go about highlighting text in css or jQuery. I want to have an image on the left and one on the right and then a repeated image in between. There are a few long words using this so I need it to be as dynamic as possible.

What i need it to look like:

[image]

Can anyone give me guidance as how to go about doing something like this? For illustration purposes we can call the images ImgLeft.png ImgRepeat.png and imgRight.png

The HTML would just be a paragraph

```
<p class="HighlightedText">Attention to detail</p>
```

Comment: Did you consider using multiple CSS backgrounds? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: Wrap in a `span` and use `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors to add the left/right background edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, you can specify multiple background images (and their associated properties) like this:

```
. HighlightedText {
    background-image: url('ImgLeft.png'), url('ImgRepeat.png'), url('ImgRight.png');
    background-position: left cneter, center center, right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, no-repeat;
}
```

Make sure the paths to the images are correct. You might need to adjust the size as well with `background-size`.